# Moto 360 accelerometer giving really weird values

Tags: accelerometer, wear-os, moto-360

We recently launched our Android Wear app Coffee [Google Play Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.awear.coffee)!

Users can launch the app by flicking their wrist. Essentially, when the watch wakes up we register with the accelerometer and start looking for a flick motion and when the watch dims we deregister.

This works on all devices except the Moto 360. When debugging we're finding that the Moto 360 accelerometer amplitude is about 10% of what we're seeing on other devices and we're only getting about 10Hz on the accelerometer.

Has anyone else seen issues like these on the Moto 360?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured this out.

The Moto 360 accelerometer is fine. The problem is that whenever you're attached for debugging over bluetooth (which is how I captured the accelerometer data) everything slows down so bad on the Moto 360 that the accelerometer data is useless.

When using the MessageAPI to send the data and not being attached the values are fine.